# Mean and variance of an exponential(theoretical and empiric)

Tags: r, statistics

So I had to find the aproximation of mean of 10**6 exponential distribution v.a. Now I have to find the exact value.

But I don't know how to implement the lambda in R and do the 1/lambda.
Can you guys help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the task you are trying to perform? If you wanted an approximation to the expected value and variance of a given distribution, you could simulate a large sample of accordingly distributed random numbers and take the empirical mean and variance, respectively. The exact value could be derived on paper :D